# Npgsql error - The store type 'nvarchar(MAX)' could not be found in the Npgsql provider manifest

Tags: npgsql

I'm new to Postgres and using npgsql as the provider to EF6. Just to provide some context, I've recently migrated our SQL Server to Aurora Postgres using the AWS DMS. That seems to be all good; I can see data and tables, etc...Now, I'm trying to hook up our application (in C# using EF6) to switch over to the Postgres DB. I've gone through all the steps to setup npgsql and npgsql EF provider, and making a new additional db context to connect to the Postgres DB. All seems good at this point.

I decided to do a simple EF query to fetch.

```
var courses = context.Courses.FirstOrDefault();
```

I got this exception:

```
An Internal Server Error has occurred|System.InvalidOperationException: The store type 'nvarchar(MAX)' could not be found in the Npgsql provider manifest
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass47_0.<Configure>b__0(Tuple`2 pm)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType entityType, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.CountAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.CountAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

Anyone know what this means?

Comment: Might want to post how your wiring up the npgsql EF provider, and related mappings.

Comment: `nvarchar(max)` is a SQL Server database type; PostgreSQL typically uses `text`. You have some remaining SQL Server-specific stuff in your project - specifically check any migrations, which contain database-specific types etc.

Comment: @ShayRojansky That was it. Looks like there are a few properties in the code with the attributes decorated with `[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]`  Also a few places where the configuration is set like this `Property(i => i.Start).HasColumnType("datetime2")`  Any ideas how I can set it with npgsql to ignore these? I still need them for the SQL Server EF. Essentially, I have two dbContext, one for MS SQL and the other for Postgres...Kind of like, allow it for MS SQL but for npgsql use text or datetime instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [these EF docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) on how to manage migrations with multiple databases.

Comment: not relevant link the issue is caused by some improper type mapping, Migrations with Multiple Providers is not relevant to that

Comment: @ArtemVertiy the improper type name above (`nvarchar(MAX)`) is a SQL Server type, which the OP was trying to apply to PostgreSQL. The OP also explicitly mentioned in their last comment that they use both MS SQL and PostgreSQL.